# Compile/build our own libffmpeg.so supporting H264

Tags: compiling, ffmpeg, dynamic-linking

How to create/compile our own libffmpeg.so supporting H264 (or H265 too) codec, just as instruction on
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
is for standalone executable build, no dynamic link build explanation was found. Thanks before

Comment: If Ubuntu is really open source, it should be possible to obtain information on how Ubuntu package ffmpeg was created.  Why do you need dynamic?  How do you see that your referred instruction does not give dynamic?

Comment: FFmpeg does not provide a library named libffmpeg.